# Data Augmentation Implementation using TensorFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

My data augmentation code in TensorFlow seems to be running, but not properly serving the intended purposes. I have a tensor with  an 'in_batch' number of images in a shape of `[in_batch, height, width, 3]` and apply the `data_augment` function below.

The run time increases when I apply data augmentation compared to the model without it, so the function is definitely being run. However, the test accuracy drops significantly, i.e. about 80% without data augmentation to about 10% with. What is happening?

```
def prep_data_augment(input_tensor, i):
    image = tf.slice(input_tensor, [i, 0, 0, 0], [1, 32, 32, 3])[0]
    image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)
    image = tf.image.random_brightness(image, max_delta=63)
    image = tf.image.random_contrast(image, lower=0.2, upper=1.8)
    image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
    return image

def data_augment(input_tensor, in_batch):
    fake_i = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int32, trainable=False)
    i = 0
    output_tensor = prep_data_augment(input_tensor, i)
    i += 1

    def while_body(output_tensor, i):
        output_tensor = tf.concat(0, [output_tensor, prep_data_augment(input_tensor, i)])
        i += 1
        return (output_tensor, i)

    (output_tensor, i) = tf.while_loop(lambda output_tensor, i: tf.less(i, in_batch), 
                                       lambda output_tensor, i: while_body(output_tensor, i), 
                                       (output_tensor, i), 
                                       shape_invariants = (tf.TensorShape([None, 32, 32, 3]), fake_i.get_shape()))
    return output_tensor
```

[ Update ]
Instead of using the while loop, the above function could be simplified by using the map function as below.

```
def prep_data_augment(image):
    image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)
    image = tf.image.random_brightness(image, max_delta=63/255.0)
    image = tf.image.random_contrast(image, lower=0.2, upper=1.8)
    return image

def data_augment(input_tensor):
    output_tensor = tf.map_fn(prep_data_augment, input_tensor)
    return output_tensor
```

Comment: LOL Hi Kumiko, it's Zhongyu from MLND slack, just happen to see your post here. Did you concat your original data tensor with your augmented tensor before feed into your network? Also my past experience tells me after you concat your original tensor with your augmented tensor, you should random shuffle the data before feeding into the network...

Comment: Hi Zhongyu! Thanks for your input. It turns out that the main problem was my max_delta parameter figure in the tf.image.random_brightness function. With the CIFAR-10 data, I divided all of the input data (RGB figures) by 255.0 when converting the type from uint8 into float32 so that I could properly display them with matplotlib. And with the delta figure, I needed to do the same. And I converted the data into float32 because that's the TensorFlow default and it was convenient to store it that way. ^_^

Comment: Glad to know that you identified the problem!

Comment: Can you share link to your entire code? I am curious how you used this for both training and test sets?